# How to modify a gzipped file with sed and then zip again the file?

Tags: bash, sed, gzip

I have a .vcf.gz file, with the following aspect:

```
#CHROM  POS     ID      REF     ALT          
chr1    10894   chr1:10894:G:A  G       A         
chr1    10915   chr1:10915:G:A  G       A          
chr1    10930   chr1:10930:G:A  G       A
```

I want to modify the CHROM column to remove 'chr' and to replace it with nothing, so I want to get a result like the following:

```
#CHROM  POS     ID      REF     ALT          
1    10894   chr1:10894:G:A  G       A         
1    10915   chr1:10915:G:A  G       A          
1    10930   chr1:10930:G:A  G       A
```

Therefore, I wrote the following command line:

```
zcat input.vcf.gz | sed 's/^chr//' > output.vcf.gz
```

and it worked. The problem is that I want to save the output file as a zipped one, with the vcf.gz extension. Even if I wrote 'output.vcf.gz', the output file is not zipped.

How can I modify a zipped file and then save it as a zipped file again?

Many thanks!

Comment: Note that for this particular file type, you should use [`bgzip`](https://www.htslib.org/doc/bgzip.html) instead of `gzip`. This is a drop-in replacement for `gzip` but it supports block compression and this allows it to then be indexed by `tabix` and be used by standard tools like `bcftools`.

Comment: If it's a VCF file with a Tabix index, you will also have to remember to re-build that index (which will require that you use `bgzip` as terdon pointed out).

Comment: @terdon huh! `bgzip`! I learn something new every day!

Comment: It's specific to this kind of file, @MarcusMüller, I don't know that it is even used outside the field of bioinformatics.

Comment: @terdon yeah, I've never heard of it – but even so, we get quite a few bioinformatics questions around here; and I've always wondered why someone with 100s of MB of actual data would want to use text-based formats (you're not going to read through the genome of Drosophila using `nano`…), and the best I came up with is "oh, these compress probably down to pretty much 0 redundancy using Lempel-Ziv", so I then assumed that entropy compression/decompression was very central to bioinformatics workflows – which then left me to wonder about the indexing problem. This highlights one possible solution!

Comment: (still, as someone with a source coding background, there *has* to be better ways than small-blocked entropy encoders on chains of characters…)

Comment: @MarcusMüller this is a biiiig subject and kinda off topic here, but please feel free to ping me in [/dev/chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26/dev-chat) if you're curious about it. This is what I do for a living in real life :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply add gzip in the pipe:

```
zcat input.vcf.gz | sed 's/^chr//' | gzip > output.vcf.gz
```

Answer (score 12):

`zcat` is really but a convenience function of `gzip`; to cite the `gzip`/`gunzip`/`zcat` manual page (`man zcat`):

> The `zcat` command is identical to `gunzip -c`.

Just as you can use `gunzip -c` (or `zcat`) in a piped chain of programs, you can use `gzip` to compress again:

```bash
zcat input.vcf.gz | sed 's/^chr//' | gzip > output.vcf.gz
#                                    ^^^^
```

or

```bash
gunzip -c input.vcf.gz | sed 's/^chr//' | gzip > output.vcf.gz
#^^^^^^^^                                 ^^^^
```

if you like consistency.

That's it. That's all there is to it.

Oh, taking a bet here: you're doing bioinformatics, and your vcf file is actually a "Variant Call Format" file, and can be rather large. `gzip` isn't a very fast decompressor, and a rather slow compressor. If you're stuck using the gzip compression file format,

```bash
unpigz -c input.vcf.gz | sed 's/^chr//' | pigz > output.vcf.gz
#^^^^^^^^                                 ^^^^
```

`pigz` does exactly the same as `gzip`, but scales to multiple CPU cores. Use it.

If you're *not* bound to keep these files in a gzip container, but are free to choose a more modern format,

```bash
unpigz -c input.vcf.gz | sed 's/^chr//' | zstd   -T0   -8 > output.vcf.zst
# decompress using     |                | ^^^^   ^^^   ^^
# unpigz instead of    |     modify     |  \--\   \-\   \\  compression ratio
# gzip/zcat            |                |      \     \    \ -0=very fast 18=very compressed
#                      |                |       \     \     -8 is much better compressed
#                      |                |        \     \    than gzip --best, but faster
#                      |                |         \     \
#                      |                |          \     \- Use as many threads as CPU cores
#                      |                |           \
#                      |                |            \
#                      |                |             \---- Use zstd instead of gzip
```

Comment: @MarcusMüller I would still keep it, but I hear what you're saying. I also, personally, favour `gzip -d` to `gunzip` in scripts.

Comment: @Kusalananda same, but we've already got one mental redirection from `zcat` to `gunzip` in the man page, I didn't want to drop more indirection at the poor reader

Comment: Oh hey, I'm sorry, I didn't mean to imply there was anything wrong here, I was just wondering if there was a specific reason, maybe some edge case, which made using `-c` safer or something. I had already upvoted.

Comment: @terdon no such implication was assumed :) It was just that I took your question, thought about it, and came to the conclusion that it's not what people would expect in that place :)